# Where is the ClickOnce "Show Desktop Icon" option? (VS2008 SP1)

Tags: .net, clickonce, icons

Apparently in VS2008 SP1 there's an option under Publish | Options to have a desktop shortcut for ClickOnce, but I've got VS2008 with SP1 and there's no such option!

[My Publish Options page](http://screencast.com/t/7MA87a6tZ9h)

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain you're running VS2008? My "Publish Options" dialog looks nothing like that. It's a tabbed affair nowadays with a "Manifests" tab (which is where you'll find the "Create desktop shortcut" checkbox).

Comment: Well crap beats me. Thanks for letting me know!